# How to update nested div and span

Tags: jquery, html

Need to update nested div and span.

HTML:

```
<table id="item_table" data-role="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th scope="col" width="100px">Name</th>
        <th scope="col" width="100px">Address</th>
        <th scope="col" width="150px">Status</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

    <tr class="item" id="APPLE">
        <td>APPLE</td>
        <td width="100px"></td>
        <td width="100px"></td>
        <td width="50px">
        <div id="item-status">
            <img id="status-image" src=""></img>
            <div>
                <span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

How to write jquery code so that the row's very last column can be updated like this. Need to update class for id="item-status" and also add img

```
<td width="50px">
<div id="item-status" class="not_found">
    <img src="some_image.png"></img>
    <div>
        <span>
            Not found
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```js
$('#item-status').addClass('myNewClass');
$('#item-status > img').attr('src', 'imagepath');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="item_table" data-role="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th scope="col" width="100px">Name</th>
      <th scope="col" width="100px">Address</th>
      <th scope="col" width="150px">Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="item" id="APPLE">
      <td>APPLE</td>
      <td width="100px"></td>
      <td width="100px"></td>
      <td width="50px">
        <div id="item-status">
          <img id="status-image" src="" />
          <div>
            <span></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```